# NodeGit how do I get a list of local branches?

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

I'm writing a node API server that needs to send user a list of local branches in a git repo residing on the server. A lot of places suggest using the [Repository#getReferenceNames](http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#getReferenceNames) from NodeGit and this is what I do:

```
exports.getBranches = function (req, res) {
    NodeGit.Repository.open(config.database).then(function(repo) {
        return repo.getReferenceNames(NodeGit.Reference.TYPE.LISTALL);
    }).then(function (arrayString) {
        res.status(200).json({message: "OK", data: arrayString});
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err, data: []});
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("finish");
    });
};
```

However, this function returns all the branches. Is there a way to only get local branch like the command line `git branch` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is! The local branches are prefixed refs/heads, while the remote branches are prefixed refs/remotes, like this:

[image]

Good luck!

**Edit:**

There is even a better method. You can traverse the returned references before returning it, and weed out the remotes with reference.isRemote().